# How can I run a containerized task in the cloud 24/7

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, aws-fargate

I have just begun to play around with various cloud vendors (AWS, GCP, etc) to get a better understanding of what they have to offer.

This is what I am looking to do: I have a task that runs 24/7 that I want to containerize and deploy to the cloud. What cloud vendor and service should I use to accomplish this? I am not very educated in the cloud space and am trying to learn more by doing.

I have looked at GKE on GCP to manage the containers, but also have read about AWS Fargate. I'm not sure what to go with, or even if the two resources I looked in to are best fitting for what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance to all of those who reply. I understand that this question is not super technical and is more opinion based, but I am genuinely curious and don't really know where to begin.

Edit:

Say I have the following code I wish to run (`my_task.py`):

```
while True:
    print("Hello World")
```

Comment: A good answer requires a good question that details the resources that your application requires. Your example is very poor and would result in high costs just logging your print statement. Create a real example that details what the app does, resources required and desired performance. Include the interface to the app such as HTTP, REST API, etc. There are many container services such as VMs running Docker (start here to learn), serverless containers, Kubernetes, Swarm, Nomad, etc. There are many tutorials and getting started guides on the Internet. Search and read a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution using GCP could be:

1. Have the application in Docker-Image
2. Run the Docker-Image as the single-workload on a Google Compute Engine: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#deploying_a_container_on_a_new_vm_instance

This is very simple and straight-forward solution for a simple use-case.